# Simplified/PHP/CGI alike django application deployment

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment, uwsgi

### what this is about

I am looking for a possibility to simplify the deployment of django applications on my server. Currently I am using one uWSGI instance per application. I do not want to mess around with configuration files whenever I uploaded a new project to my www-root-folder. Instead I am looking for a more php alike solution, where I can upload a project folder to my www-root and have it available through nginx-> uWSGI or nginx-> Gunicorn "automatically" and without having to modify a configuration file. Also it would be ideal not to have a process for each application, so that I do not waste memory *(as I am never using more than one application at a time)*.

### current state

For that I have found, that uWSGI's [emperor mode for django applications](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#emperor-mode) in combination with [magic variables](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html) may work. But with my configuration only settings from one django application gets and stays loaded, so that no other can start.

from `uwsgi.conf.template`:

```
[uwsgi]
master             =  true
socket             =  :8000
master             =  true
reuse-port         =  true
reload-os-env      =  true
vaccuum            =  true
logto              =  /var/log/uwsgi-%n.log
manage-script-name =  true
chdir              =  /usr/local/www/%n
mount              =  /%n=%n/wsgi.py
```

from `nginx.conf`:

```
location ~ ^/(.+)/(.+?)$
{
   include uwsgi_params;
   uwsgi_pass 10.0.0.106:8000;
   uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT $1.wsgi;
   uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /$1;
   uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /usr/local/www/$1;
   uwsgi_param PATH_INFO "/$2"; # strip path
 }


 location ~ ^/(.+)/$
 {
   include uwsgi_params;
   uwsgi_pass 10.0.0.106:8000;
   uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT $1.wsgi;
   uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $1;
   # uwsgi_param UWSGI_APPID /$1;
   uwsgi_param DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE $1.settings;
   uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR /usr/local/www/$1;
   uwsgi_param PATH_INFO '';
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around another day I got to the point where I have a working solution. It won't be the final solution, but it works for now and I will try to update this answer whenever I improve this configuration again.

### Basic configuration

This is somehow close to what one can find in the [documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html). I found it nevertheless kind of hard to get it working this way.

`nginx.conf`

```
server
{
  server_name test.example.com;
  listen [::]:80;

  location ~ ^/(.+)/static/(.+)$
  { alias /usr/local/www/$1/static/$2; }

  location ~ ^/(.+)/media/(.+)$
  { alias /usr/local/www/$1/media/$2; }

  location ~ ^/(.*?)/
  {
    uwsgi_pass unix:///var/run/uwsgi/$1.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;        
  }
}
```

`/usr/local/www/uwsgi.skel`

```
[uwsgi]
master             =  true
socket             =  /var/run/uwsgi/%c.sock
reuse-port         =  true
master             =  true
reload-os-env      =  true
vaccuum            =  true
logto              =  /var/log/uwsgi/%c.log
manage-script-name =  true
chdir              =  /usr/local/www/%c
touch-reload       =  /usr/local/www/%c/%c
wsgi-file          =  %c/wsgi.py
mount              =  /%c=%c/wsgi.py
static-map         =  /static=/usr/local/www/%c/static
static-map         =  /media=/usr/local/www/%c/media
unenv              =  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
unenv              =  DJANGO_SETTINGS
wsgi-env-behaviour =  holy
print              =  we are using %c
```

We must create the required folders for socket- and log-files and take care for the necessary permissions (also see below). Also note, that `/var/run/` may not survive a reboot on your OS, so that another folder may be better suited:

```
chmod -R www:www /usr/local/www
mkdir /var/log/uwsgi/
chmod -R www:www /var/log/uwsgi/
mkdir /var/run/uwsgi/
chmod -R www:www /var/run/uwsgi/
```

### Launching the uWSGI master instance...

We can now launch the uwsgi process in emperor mode, even in [emperor-tyrant](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Emperor.html#tyrant-mode-secure-multi-user-hosting) mode:

```
uwsgi --emperor 'glob:///usr/local/www/*/uwsgi.ini' --emperor-nofollow --emperor-tyrant \
--master --thunder-lock --enable-threads
```

And here was a trick I used: The glob will try to suck a file called `uwsgi.ini` in from each directory under `/usr/local/www/`. It could have been an individual file, but I just linked the skel-file from above *(which fulfills my requirement not to have to edit a config file)*:

```
cd /usr/local/www/django-app1/
ln -s ../uwsgi.skel uwsgi.ini
```

This also comes handy because recent versions of GIT also support symlinks, so that the symlink on my development machine can have other values in the `uwsgi.skel` file (e.g. not `/usr/local/www` but `/var/www/`)

### A word on permissions and 'emperor-tyrant' mode...

The emperor-tyrant mode will make uWSGI spawn processes owned by different users. Which user that is depends on the permissions of the uwsgi.ini file. The uWSGI process then drops its privileges and runs under the username that file belongs to. I don't need that feature yet, but if you try to setup a professional hosting platform you will need it. For that to work keep in mind, that nginx must have sufficient permissions to read and write the generated socket files and that `/var/run/uwsgi/` must also be writable for all those users.

### Setting up a virtual environment

After approximately one year without a single problem I found one of my sites in a non operational state. It turned out, that it was due to an update moving towards python3. To make it short: I had to fiddle a bit, because setting up a virtual environment for one of the sites was not as trivial since I was always getting `No module named site` errors after adding `virtualenv =` to my `uwsgi.ini`. My new ini file now looks like this:

`/usr/local/www/project/uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
master             =  true
socket             =  /var/run/uwsgi/%c.sock
reuse-port         =  true
reload-os-env      =  true
vaccuum            =  true
manage-script-name =  true

logto              =  /var/log/uwsgi/%c.log
virtualenv         =  /usr/local/www/katalogpro/venv/
chdir              =  /usr/local/www/%c
touch-reload       =  /usr/local/www/%c/%c

mount              =  /%c=%c/wsgi.py
static-map         =  /static=/usr/local/www/%c/static
static-map         =  /media=/usr/local/www/%c/media
print              =  we are using %c

# set cheaper algorithm to use, if not set default will be used
cheaper-algo     = backlog
cheaper-overload = 4
cheaper-idle     = 1
cheaper-initial  = 0
```

Notice, that it has become somewhat easier, because there are less settings in it. It may be possible to further tweak that and use the configuration as `.skel`-configuration with an if statement, which automatically adds a virtualenv if there is one. For now it is working again and I am happy.

Comment: This setup is running for about half a year now and turned out to be very usable